# Why is the topologically non-trivial edge state robust against off-diagonal disorder?

Tags: topological-insulators

By numerical calculation it's easy to see that the topological non-trival edge state is robust against off-diagonal disorder, i.e., the edge state keeps exponential decay with distance in the presence of off-diagonal disorder once the disorder doesn't lead topological transition.
Here I give an example, the SSH model. For the SSH model with open boundary condition$$H=\sum_{j=1}^{N}{J(1+\delta)(a^{\dagger}_jb_j+h.c.)+\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}J(1-\delta)(a^{\dagger}_{j+1}b_j+h.c.)}$$The topological protected edge states occurs once $\delta\lt 0$. Now applying the addition of random off-diagonal disorder to the Hamiltonian$$H\to H+\sum_{j}{\epsilon_{1,j}a^{\dagger}_jb_j+\epsilon_{2,j}a^{\dagger}_{j+1}b_j+h.c.}$$Taking the factor $\epsilon_{1,j},\epsilon_{2,j}$ from a uniform distribution with in the range $\left[-w/2,w/2 \right]$ for each cell $j$ and to prevent changing the sign of the couping amplitudes between the lattice, $w$ is restricted to $w/2\lt (1-|\delta|)$.
In the presence of above off-diagonal disorder, the edge still exponentially decay with distance by numerically diagonalizing the new Hamiltonian, i.e., the edge state is robust against off-diagonal disorder. But I want to understand this by theoritical calculation. Are there any theories that make theoritical calculation of the edge state then prove it's immune from off-dianogal disorder?
I have this question because there're some papers making the statement that the $H$ with OBC is equivalent to $H$ with PBC plus a additional infinite potential $V=\eta\left|j,\alpha \right>\left< j,\alpha \right|$ for $\eta\to+\infty$. By numerically diagonalizing these two Hamiltonian, in the absence of the above off-diagonal disorder they are equivalent indeed (the edge state and corresponding energy is the same), but the edge state doesn't exponentially decay for the Hamiltonian with $V$ and the other keeps exponential for the Hamiltonian with open boundary condition once the above off-diagonal disorder appears. That's to say, these two type of Hamiltonian is not equivalent, at least, their edge state are not equivalent in the presence of ODD.

Comment: Can you give more detail?   Is this for a finite and discrete system?

Comment: @TerryLoring. I've edited my problem to show more details.